# File path is empty after submitting ASP.NET MVC form

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and I have an edit form for products. Products have images links which should be editable too.

In the DB I store just the image URL, and the model contains only this URL:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId{ get; set; }
    public string ImgUrl{ get; set;}
}
```

The form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditProduct", "Products", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <img src="@Url.Content(Model.ImgUrl)" />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ImgUrl, new { @type="file", @id="file-upload" })
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

Also I have an action method which is empty at the moment:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditProduct(Product product)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

There are two problems.

First of all after submitting the form `product.ImgUrl` is null.

The second one is that the value of `#file-upload` doesn't changes after a file is selected.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but look your class, you forgot the t  of the "set" for your ImgUrl string.

Comment: @NathanMeunier that's just a typo when typing on stackoverflow.

Comment: What about changing the id for the Textbox to "ImageUrl" instead of "file-upload"?

Comment: Why would you need the file name (in the client machine) in your server ?

Comment: ...or simply remove the id field, then it should post with the url correctly

Comment: @gardarvalur The field name sent to the server in posted forms is based on the "name" attribute of the input element, not the id. This is a basic fact of HTML forms. The ID can be anything you like. The TextBoxFor helper should take care of setting the correct "name" attribute, but OP can check that in their browser tools.

Comment: @Gleb I think your problem is that you're using a "file" input, which literally sends the actual file chosen by the user, in binary format, but your ImgUrl property is a string. A string cannot hold a file object in it. You seem to be confused between the file itself, and the URL to the file which can be generated once the file has been uploaded and stored on the server. https://cpratt.co/file-uploads-in-asp-net-mvc-with-view-models/ is quite a good tutorial on how to do it successfully.

Comment: Your right of course @ADyson, id refers to front end but name refers to server, my bad

Answer (score 5):

Try with this solution

**Model**

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase Img { get; set; } //Added new property for mvc file http support
    public string ImgUrl { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditProduct", "Products", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <img src="@Url.Content(Model.ImgUrl)" />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Img, new { @type = "file", @id = "file-upload" })
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditProduct(Product product)
{
    if (product.Img != null)
    {
        product.ImgUrl = product.Img.FileName; //or you can save anywhere and merge file name with path
    }
    return View();
}
```

> **Explanations**
>
> - The form method is POST, and the form encoding type is multipart/form-data. These parameters are required for uploading
>     binary data to the server.
> - The input element having type=”file” displays the Choose File button and the field containing a selected file name.
> - The name of the input element identifies the uploaded file in the HttpPostedFilesBase object.

[Here is nice blog explained for file upload in MVC](https://www.aurigma.com/upload-suite/developers/aspnet-mvc/how-to-upload-files-in-aspnet-mvc)